# GLSL performance issue with uniform int array larger than 246

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I just wanted to implement Perlin Noise in the fragment shader. Therefore I need to pass an uniform int array of size 512 to the fragment shader. Now this leads to horrible performance (1FPS) on my not so old mac. I tried to reduce the size of the array which yields that there is a hard limit of 246 elements in the array which still produces interactive framerates. So my question is:

- Where does this limitation come from? OSX? Graphics card? OpenGL version?
- Is there a way around this? I tried using integer textures but these aren't supported by my OS!

Has anybody experienced something similar?

Comment: Btw you might be interested in reading perlin noise article in GPU-gems [1](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter26.html), [2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch05.html)

Answer (score 3):

> Therefore I need to pass an uniform int array of size 512 to the fragment shader.

You could use a 1D texture instead. You don't even need integers, floats work for Perlin Noise just as good.

Comment: And integer textures  could be unsupported.

Comment: The problem with 1D textures is that I can't use texelFetch because it is not supported on OSX. Therefore I would need to use texture1D to get the values, which is a mess (need to care about interpolation of values and correct index normalization).

Comment: @Nicholas: Perlin Noise works regardless of that interpolation or not. The whole idea of Perlin Noise is to use the value of a octave as an offset into the next one. If you interpolate the values and keep your "indices" in the range [0; 1] it works just as fine. Here's video of a Perlin Noise implementation on a Shader Model 2 GPU, I wrote back in 2004 (using that assembly shader language) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnxDfVSKPBI – all LUTs were of type float and normalized into the [0; 1] range. **TL;DR:** There's no need for texelFetch, it works with interpolating texture1D just as well.

Answer (score 1):

It must be hardware or shader version limitation. Can you use texture instead ?